# Establish a VPN connection with react-native on android

Tags: react-native, vpn

How can I create a VPN connection (PPTP or anything else) with react-native in android and then connect to it?

Comment: I was here(Until someone wrote a lib)

Comment: @EJChathuranga what was the library? can you share it here?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [react-native-ip-sec-vpn](https://github.com/sijav/react-native-ip-sec-vpn) now!

Use it like as follow:

```
import {prepare, connect} from "react-native-ip-sec-vpn";
...
useEffect(() => {
    prepare();
}); /// or use componentDidmount in case of a class component
...
connect(address, username, password)
```