# connect vpn programmatically react native for android ios

Tags: android, ios, node.js, react-native, vpn

I am new to react native, I want to make a VPN client app for Android and IOS. 
VPN protocol should be IPSec or IKEv2 or any other. I have tried these:

**1. OpenVPN**

[node-openvpn](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-openvpn) and [openvpn-bin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/openvpn-bin) but no luck

```js
const openvpnmanager = require('node-openvpn'); **

const opts = {

  host: '127.0.0.1', // normally '127.0.0.1', will default to if undefined

  port: 1337, //port openvpn management console

  timeout: 1500, //timeout for connection - optional, will default to 1500ms if undefined

  logpath: 'log.txt' //optional write openvpn console output to file, can be relative path or absolute
};



const auth = {

  user: 'vpnUserName',

  pass: 'vpnPassword',

};

const openvpn = openvpnmanager.connect(opts)

// will be emited on successful interfacing with openvpn instance

openvpn.on('connected', () => {

  openvpnmanager.authorize(auth);

})
```

**2. react native open settings**

[react-native-device-setting](https://github.com/rjblopes/react-native-device-settings) and [react-native-open-settings](https://github.com/lunarmayor/react-native-open-settings) in which they have showed to programmatically open android phone settings like:

install package: **npm install react-native-device-settings --save**

usage:

```js
import DeviceSettings from 'react-native-device-settings';

DeviceSettings.open(); // Open settings menu

DeviceSettings.app(); // Open app settings menu

DeviceSettings.wifi(); // Open wifi settings menu
```

but there is no method to open up the VPN Settings and configure VPN. [47306057](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47306057/establish-a-vpn-connection-with-react-native-on-android) has also asked the same problem

i need some direction or way to solve this. is there a library or something that i should use or make a VPN app in android studio and then import the aar file here. will it work?

Can anyone help me out in this? Thanks