# Is there any way to establish a VPN connection using React native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, vpn

I've been learning react for the past few months. But now I need to actually use it somewhere. That is, I was assigned a task for creating a VPN app. I searched on the internet but the results were not what I was looking for. There are really awesome projects on the internet but all of them are just UI and not actual working VPN app. It's been around a week but still I'm not able to solve this issue. I haven't found any working package for establishing a VPN connection using React native. I've came across a [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47306057/establish-a-vpn-connection-with-react-native-on-android) which suggests using `react-native-ip-sec-vpn`. But there seems to be some problems. When I try to use the package it shows some errors that I couldn't solve nor found any solution on the internet. And then I came across their [GitHub issues](https://github.com/sijav/react-native-ip-sec-vpn/issues/45) and found out this problem wasn't mine alone. As far as I understood, this package can't be used for making a VPN connection. It needs to be updated.

So, in conclusion, I'm asking for a valid React native package that I can use to develop a VPN app. Any suggestions?

Comment: Asking for a tool and external resource is off-topic on StackOverflow. Try on Reddit https://www.reddit.com/r/reactnative/

Comment: Reddit is not available in my country

Comment: What? What country you're in?

Comment: I'm from Bangladesh and Reddit is blocked here.